# Ambari Thrift server auto restart at oom

Tags: thrift, ambari

I'm using Ambari 2.6.2.2 and I installed Hbase, for which I started thrift server.

How can I configure the thrift server to start at boot?

Right now, I configured only hbase to start at boot using "Service Auto-Start" from ambari.

Also , how can I configure thrift server to restart when an oom happens?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way to do this directly from Ambari.

I managed to start at boot and to autorestart using Supervisor.
Here is supervisor configure file for Thrift and Rest Servers.

```
[program:hbase-thrift]
command=hbase thrift start -p 9090 --infoport 9095
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/thrift-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/thrift-stdout.log
autorestart=true
user=hbase
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stderr_logfile_backups=5


[program:hbase-rest]
command=hbase rest start -p 9080 --infoport 9085
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/rest-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/rest-stdout.log
autorestart=true
user=hbase
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stderr_logfile_backups=5
```